How do I avoid start destination in deeplink backstack with multiple independant fragments in same navgraph?
I have a module with two independant fragment destinations. These are not connected to each other and do not navigate to one another, but since they fall under the same domain, we grouped them in one nav graph.
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentOne">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentOne"
        android:name="FragmentOne"
        android:label="Fragment One">
        <deepLink app:uri="https://myapp.com/fragmentOne" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentTwo"
        android:name="FragmentTwo"
        android:label="Fragment Two">
        <deepLink app:uri="https://myapp.com/fragmentTwo" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>

This nav graph is nested along with all other module nav graphs in the global app_nav.xml in App module.
Now the issue arises when I try to launch the app to one of these independant fragment via deeplink. The app opens as expected, however when I navigate back it takes me to the starting destination of the nav graph. The user navigates to both of these fragments directly from the home screen, and so they should have navigated to the home screen instead of Fragment One.
I understand that for me to fix this issue, I'll have to put them in separate nav graphs, but I don't want to populate my app with unnecessary graphs but also maintain it's modularity (It's a multi-module app). Is there another way to tackle this issue?
